# Will I get clash issues if I compare mongodb Ids case-insensitively?

Tags: mongodb, email, meteor

I have an email token collection in my mongodb database for a meteor app and I stick these email tokens in the reply address of my email (eg. @example.com) so that when I parse it I know what it's relating to.

The problem I have is that the email token uses the default _id algorithm to generate a unique id and that algorithm generates a string that is a mixture of upper case and lower case characters.

However, I've discovered that some email clients, lowercases the entire reply address, which means that I can only identify the addresses case-insensitvely.

I guess now I have two options.

1) The easiest option would be to match the email tokens with the reply address case insensitively. What would be the chance of clashes in that respect?

2) Make the email token some sort of guid and generate this guid independent of the mongodb ID creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would get issues. Meteor uses both upper and lower case values in its 17 character id values. You can have a look at the code in the `Random` package: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/random.

So it would be possible to get two distinct values of which the differences could only be casing. This could cause mixups if your client's email applications convert the address to lowercase characters.

In your case it is best not to use `Random.id()`, rather to make up your own Random character generator. Something like this might work:

```
var lowerCaseId = function() {
    var digits = [],
        self = this;

    for (var i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
        digits[i] = Random.choice("23456789abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    }
    return digits.join("");
};
```

Also of note is the meteor `_id` value is built up of 'unmistakeable characters' - There are no characters that can cause confusion such as 0 vs O, 1 vs I, etc.

If you don't use it in your `_id` field, you would have to generate a value with this and check it does not exist in your database before inserting it, or using a unique index for it.

Additionally also be aware there will be a significant decrease in entropy since the number of possible combinations will have dropped with the loss of the uppercased characters. If this is of significance to you, you could increase the number of digits from 17 in the code above.

Comment: wouldn't I be better off with just generating a UUID instead of creating my own function?

Comment: You could! UUIDs are hexadecimal though, so you would need more characters to make up for the same amount of data given that there are 16 possible characters in each digit. I mentioned the custom method since it gives you a bit more flexibility, depending on your use case.

Comment: ah ok, yes ur right. but in our case, more letters is not a problem

Answer (score 1):

Meteor is generating it's own Id's which are different from the MongoDB ObjectId's. As noted, these would be subject to clash when converting case or checking case insensitively. This is kind of interesting and I'm not sure of the project's reasons for this.

Under the hood however the mongodb node native driver. So the ObjectId creation functions should be available if you want to use them.

https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/master/lib/bson/objectid.js#L68-L74

The important part is in these calls:

```
value.toString(16)
```

So the radix here is set to 16 for hex or all the characters 0-9a-f.

You can also note in drivers that they will Regex check like this:

```
^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$
```

So it would seem that case sensitivity is not an issue.

Still if you want to use something alternate there is a section in the documentation that might serve as a useful guide.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#the-id-field

Comment: This would not apply to the `_id`s generated with meteor as they're not hexadecimal (0-9a-fA-F). They would consist of the full alphabet without mistakable characters.

Comment: @Akshat [Facepalm] Totally missed the meteor part. You are totally right there.